# How to access base class method after downcasting?

Tags: java, oop

This is a Java Generics program that implements a custom interface with set(T t), get() and print(T t) methods.

The class that I use is called Animal. It takes a T argument (String in this case) and gives the animal a name.

My problem is that I can't access any of the Animal class methods in my print function.

```
Animal<String> a1 = new Animal();
a1.set("Mickey");

public void print(Object o) {
  Animal oAnimal = (Animal) o; //Downcasting from Object to Animal.

  System.out.println(o.get()); //not accessible, and I don't know how to make it accessible.
//I can only access the methods from Object, not my custom class called Animal.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're still trying to call the method on `o`, which is still of type `Object` (in terms of the compile-time type of the variable, which is all the compiler cares about).

If you call the method on `oAnimal` instead, it will be fine:

```
System.out.println(oAnimal.get());
```

(You can't *return* the result of `System.out.println` though, as it's a void method. Nor can you specify a return value for *your* void method.)

Note that this has nothing to do with generics, really. The code in your question can be demonstrated simply using `String`:

```
Object o = "foo";
String text = (String) o;
System.out.println(o.length()); // Error; Object doesn't have a length() method
System.out.println(text.length()); // Prints 3
```

Your (edited) question does demonstrate a use of generics, but your cast to `Animal` is a cast to a *raw* type, so it's simpler just to leave generics out of the equation - the reason for the compilation failure has nothing to do with `Animal` being generic.

Answer (score 9):

You should use

`oAnimal.get()`

since that's the instance of `Animal`.

Remember you are not modifying `o`, so it will remain as an `Object`.